# Stemming Search Using SnowballPorterFilterFactory Seems to Return Less Results

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have 4 documents containing the following 4 texts respectively.

- xxx do xxx
- xxx does xxx
- xxx did xxx
- xxx doing xxx

Now I perform a search by the text "**do**" using the **SnowballPorterFilterFactory** filter, and expect to search all the above 4 documents out. But only the following documents are searched out.

- xxx do xxx
- xxx doing xxx

But when I try the search by the text "**refactor**", all documents containing the texts "**refactor**", "**refactors**", "**refactored**" or "**refactoring**" are searched out.

Why does the search by the text "**do**" cannot return the documents containing "**does**" and "**did**"? Is the word "**do**" somewhat special and shouldn't using the **SnowballPorterFilterFactory** filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that surprised: all the forms of do are declared as stop words in the stop words list provided with the SnowballFilter in Lucene so they probably didn't care about this case.

So it's more or less consistent with their intents.

You can either:
* use a StopFilterFactory with the provided english_stop.txt (read the comment at the top of the file about the format to use); note that searching on only the term do/doing/did won't work (but I don't think it's a use case per se) but they will be ignored if they are part of a larger search, thus solving your issue.
* declare them as synonyms with a SynonymFilterFactory.

Either way, welcome to the wonderful world of stemming: it's really not an easy subject.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solutions. I will try them later. And thanks for the welcome, ^_^.